# Fixitnow its cold ...please

Tags: engine, ford, heat

Just put heater core in and no heat .water pump was replaced not long ago and it's sucking the top radiator hose together .
How do you berp the air out

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If it's sucking the top radiator hose together, the radiator hose needs to be replaced. They become weak over time. It can also cause overheating of the engine as well. Have you tested your thermostat to ensure it's in good shape? Could be causing issues as well. What was the reason for changing out the heater core? Was it leaking? To help you know how to burp your car, we need to know the year/make/model/engine of it.

Comment: Sounds like Ford are still making cooling systems with the same problem they had back in the 1970s (which was the first, and last, time I ever owned a Ford - getting the cooling system full or water not air was just one of many issues....)